# Why are nonzero eigenvalues of a compact operator poles of its resolvent?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators, meromorphic-functions

Let $X$ be a complex Banach space and $T$ a compact operator on $X$. I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_compact_operators) that nonzero elements of the spectrum of $T$ are poles of its resolvent. It says "by functional calculus", but I don't see how.

I'm looking for a reference or a sketch of the proof. At the moment I have no idea how it goes.

---

By reading Yosida's "Functional Analysis" I know that an eigenvalue is a pole when its residue has finite rank (VIII.8, Theorem 4). But I don't see why / know if residues have finite rank when $T$ is compact.

I can show that those isolated singularities are poles when $T$ is normal and trace class, using the spectral theorem and by investigating its Laurent-coefficients. But I don't want to assume that $T$ is normal.

Comment: See Proposition VII.6.12 in Conway's Functional Analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof that the residue of the resolvent at an eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$ has finite rank, is sketched at that same wikipedia page, in the section "Invariant subspaces". The residue is called the *Riesz projection* $E(\lambda)$.

Combinated with that result from Yosida's book, the conclusion follows.

---

Since the Wikipedia page does not give much details, here are some more: The invertibility of the restriction of $C:=T$ to $E(\lambda)$ follows from the properties of [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus):
$$\int \frac{C}{\xi - C} d\xi = \int \frac{\xi}{\xi - C} d\xi = \left(\int \frac{\xi^{-1}}{\xi - C} d\xi \right)^{-1}$$
Thus $C$ is compact and invertible on the range of $E(\lambda)$, hence this space has finite dimension. We can stop here and use Yosida's Theorem 4, but there is a shortcut:

That the spectrum of the restriction is $\{\lambda\}$ follows from the spectral mapping theorem for holomorphic functional calculus.

Finally, by finite-dimensional linear algebra, we have $(C-\lambda)^nE(\lambda) = 0$ for $n$ sufficiently large, and from the following formula for the Laurent coefficients of the resolvent:
$$A_{-(n+1)} = (C-\lambda I)^n A_{-1}$$
(Cf. Yosida VIII.8 Theorem 2, but this is elementary) we conclude that $\lambda$ is a pole.

Answer (score 4):

If a bounded operator $T$ has an isolated point $\lambda_0$ of its spectrum $\sigma(T)$, then the resolvent is holomorphic in a punctured neighborhood of $\lambda_0$, which ensures a Laurent series expansion with operator coefficients $C_n$:
$$
       (T-\lambda I)^{-1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(\lambda-\lambda_0)^n C_n,\;\;r < |\lambda-\lambda_0| < R
$$
If you multiply by $T-\lambda_0 I$, you find
$$
     (T-\lambda_0 I)(T-\lambda I)^{-1}=I+(\lambda-\lambda_0)(T-\lambda I)^{-1}\\
  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(\lambda-\lambda_0)^n(T-\lambda_0 I)C_n = I+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(\lambda-\lambda_0)^{n+1}C_n.
$$
Equating coefficients gives

$$
    (T-\lambda_0 I)C_n=C_{n-1},\;\; n \ne 0.
$$
Therefore $(T-\lambda_0I)^kC_{-1}=C_{-k-1}$.

The following is a projection:
$$
   C_{-1} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\lambda-\lambda_0|=r}(\lambda I-T)^{-1}d\lambda.
$$ 
That is, $C_{-1}^2=C_{-1}$. Furthermore, $(T-\lambda_0I)$ is nilpotent on $C_{-1}X$, provided $r$ is chosen so that the punctured closed disk $\{ \lambda : 0 < |\lambda-\lambda_0| \le r\}$ is contained in the resolvent set of $T$.
Because $C_{-N-1}=(T-\lambda_0 I)^{N}C_{-1}=0$ for some $N$, it follows that the resolvent has a pole at $\lambda_0$.

Comment: Thank you. My main issue was to understand why $T-\lambda_0 I$ is nilpotent on $C_{-1}X$, which I managed to clarify in my answer.